# CPU vs Memory trade-offs when using instanced drawing w/ many unique primitives

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm using OpenGL ES 2 on iOS to render a (relatively) huge 2D grid where the squares ("pixels") are disjointed -- spaced, instead of in a checkerboard pattern -- and outlined, and am having the worst time trying to figure out an efficient way to draw it such that each square and outline of that square can be assigned a different color, as this is for a drawing app. The grid must be able to represent up to 1024x1024 "pixels".

Originally, I tried the approach of putting all of my vertex data in a massive buffer and rendering that with a single `glDrawArrays` call each frame, but, as you might expect, the memory usage was unreasonable and that was only with the outlines (made with GL_LINES) -- no fills. Further research taught me about instanced drawing, which I'm doing now via `glDrawArraysInstancedEXT`, but, of course, 1024*1024 instanced draw calls are killing the CPU/FPS. I would guess that the solution to this problem lies somewhere between the two approaches -- draw a larger primitive of "grouped" GL_TRIANGLE_STRIPs using degenerate vertices to separate the resulting squares... but then I don't think I can give each square it's own color. Needless to say, I'm still learning; how does one usually draw massive quantities of simple, same, but uniquely-colored polygons??

The relevant code...

```
static const int numColumns = 1024;
static const int numRows = 1024;
static const GLfloat outlineVertices[] = {
    0.1f, -0.1f,
    0.9f, -0.1f,
    0.1f, -0.9f,
    0.9f, -0.9f
};
static const GLfloat innerVertices[] = {
    0.2f, -0.2f,
    0.8f, -0.2f,
    0.2f, -0.8f,
    0.8f, -0.8f
};

- (void)setupGL
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    [self loadShaders];

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(outlineVertices), outlineVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    glUseProgram(_program);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
    glUniform1i(uniforms[NUM_COLUMNS], numColumns);
    glUniform1i(uniforms[NUM_ROWS], numRows);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(outlineVertices), outlineVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glUniform1i(uniforms[DRAWING_INNER], 0);
    glDrawArraysInstancedEXT(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4, numColumns * numRows);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(innerVertices), innerVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glUniform1i(uniforms[DRAWING_INNER], 1);
    glDrawArraysInstancedEXT(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4, numColumns * numRows);
}

vshader:
#extension GL_EXT_draw_instanced : enable

attribute vec4 vertices;

varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;

uniform int numColumns;
uniform int numRows;
uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform int drawingInner;

void main()
{
    if (drawingInner == 0) {
        colorVarying = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    } else {
        colorVarying = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }

    float column = mod(float(gl_InstanceIDEXT), float(numColumns));
    float row = -(float(gl_InstanceIDEXT / numColumns));

    gl_Position = vec4(vertices.x + column, vertices.y + row, vertices.zw) * modelViewProjectionMatrix;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, including tips on best practices. Is there a way to draw this massive grid efficiently without changing the data based on what the user is currently seeing... some sort of manual culling? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best to just do this in the fragment shader.  This way, you can just use plain, ordinary textures, and you can forget about having to render anything more than a single quad.  Here is a shader that draws a grid, with different foreground / background colors for each pixel.  It is written to run inside ShaderToy, so you will have to adapt it for your program.

I put a [live demo on ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xd33DX) (which is a little different from the code below, so it can run on ShaderToy).

### Fragment Shader

```c
precision mediump float;

// Texture coordinates, from 0 to 1
varying vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D FGTex;
uniform sampler2D BGTex;
// Texture size, in pixels.
uniform vec2 TexSize;
// Width of grid lines, from 0 to 1
uniform float GridWidth;

void main() {
    // Get the foreground and background colors
    vec4 fgColor = texture2D(FGTex, TexCoord);
    vec4 bgColor = texture2D(BGTex, TexCoord);
    // Calculate the grid
    vec2 gridPos = fract(TexCoord * TexSize + GridWidth * 0.5);
    vec2 gridFrac = step(GridWidth, gridPos);
    gl_FragColor = mix(bgColor, fgColor, gridFrac.x * gridFrac.y);
}
```

### Results

[image: screenshot of result]

Note that the grid lines are inconsistent unless you do the math exactly right to get them to line up, but you have to do that anyway.

Comment: This is brilliant. I have yet to implement it, but after researching fragment shaders and those functions considerably, I see what's going in and this definitely looks like the way to go. One supplemental question, if you don't mind... if I wanted to apply a bezier path to the grid lines to make them round, would I do that in the fragment shader as well with a more complex step-mixing routine? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Bézier path: no, that can be prohibitively expensive, as well as difficult to write.  However, circles would be easy.  In fact, the easiest way to get any shape you want is to just use a texture for the pixel shape.